# RestTemplate put method

Tags: java, resttemplate

I have a controller with this method on service side

```
@PutMapping("/libraryBranches/libraryBranch/updateNumberOfCopies")
public ResponseEntity<LibraryBranch> updateNumberOfcopies(@RequestParam("numberOfCopies") int numberOfCopies,
        @RequestParam("bookId") long bookId, @RequestParam("branchId") long branchId) {
    bookCopiesRepository.updateNumberOfCopies(numberOfCopies, bookId, branchId);
    return new ResponseEntity<LibraryBranch>(HttpStatus.OK);
}
```

What will be the method on the client side for this resource ?

Comment: Is this a trick question? `PUT localhost/<servlet path>/<controller path if any>/libraryBranches/libraryBranch/updateNumberOfCopies?numberOfCopies=1&bookId=2&branchId=3`. RestTemplate has both put and exchange methods depending on what you need to pass (eg headers, etc.)

Comment: on the server side resource is located on ""http://localhost:8091/lms/librarian/libraryBranches/libraryBranch/updateNumberOfCopies"", it is put method with (@RequestParam("numberOfCopies") int numberOfCopies,
        @RequestParam("bookId") long bookId, @RequestParam("branchId") long branchId). My question is how can i pass all these parames from client side to server side ? http://localhost:8091/lms/librarian/libraryBranches/libraryBranch/updateNumberOfCopies?numberOfCopies=1&bookId=2&branchId=3  this simply is not working

Comment: @Vladimir, You use PUT or GET(by browser)?

Comment: If you're just clicking the browser link, you're doing a GET. Do a PUT using curl or wget or something like postman, and set the request parameters like I showed in my example url.

Comment: Is your client Java? Then use RestTemplate. Is it a browser? You may use jQuery‘s $.ajax.

Comment: i have test app on localhost:8091, i already posted the method above, it is a put method with hidden request parameters, now my task is to call this method from lets's say another app localhost:8080. Question ? how i should i call this method on 8080 using rest Template exchange method ? my difficulty is to send @reguestParameters (int , long, long) to method on 8091. if append locallhost:8091/lms.librarian/LibraryBranches/libraryBrances + reguestParametes here, simply is not working because on 8091 i have strictly locallhost:8091/lms.librarian/LibraryBranches/libraryBrances

Comment: for test purpose i am using swagger, so i am  putting  in swagger all these @RequestParam("numberOfCopies") int numberOfCopies,
        @RequestParam("bookId") long bookId, @RequestParam("branchId")

Comment: how should my method looks on 8080 asking the  resource 8091 ?

Answer (score 0):

I don't see where the problem is..

```
String url = "http://localhost:8080/libraryBranches/libraryBranch/updateNumberOfCopies";
RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

HttpHeaders httpHeaders = new HttpHeaders();
httpHeaders.add(HttpHeaders.AUTHORIZATION, "urAccessToken");

UriComponentsBuilder builder = UriComponentsBuilder.fromUriString(url)
        .queryParam("numberOfCopies", "")
        .queryParam("bookId", "")
        .queryParam("branchId", "");

HttpEntity httpEntity = new HttpEntity(httpHeaders);

restTemplate.exchange(builder.toUriString(), HttpMethod.PUT, httpEntity, LibraryBranch.class);
```